What is Excel formula to show Top N by category?
I have a Spill Array. How can I take only top 1 for each product. Basically I want to filter to only values highlighted in yellow.
Formula for Spill Array
=GROUPBY(HSTACK(SL_2025[Product],SL_2025[Description],SL_2025[Root Cause]),SL_2025[Total Adjusted Shortage],SUM,0,0,-4,COUNTIF(Filters!C2#,SL_2025[Sales Office])*COUNTIF(Filters!G2#,SL_2025[Fiscal Week]))
Spill Array: https://i.sstatic.net/ox9ZcJA4.png
I tried to use FILTER function in BYROW but I get an error.
=BYROW(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(H66#,1)), LAMBDA(x, TAKE(FILTER(H66#,CHOOSECOLS(H66#,1)=x,0),1)))

What error are you getting?

I get this: #CALC!

Use REDUCE and VSTACK the FILTER results.

@ScottCraner - that was is! Thank you for the hint.

Alternatively =CHOOSEROWS(H66:K84,XMATCH(UNIQUE(H66:H84),H66:H84))  With BYROWS, you have to return a single scalar, not an array.
